# What's the STL way to fill a 2-dimensional std::array without iteration?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, stl

I have a 2-dimensional `std::array` of `std::array`s and I want to fill it with 0s. The only solution to this that I found is to use a pointer to the first element and `sizeof`, like so:

```
std::fill(&arr2d[0][0], &arr2d[0][0] + sizeof(arr2d), 0);
```

Although it works, it doesn't line up with other methods I've found for filling 1D `std::array`s without pointer logic, like the following two:

```
std::fill(arr1d.begin(), arr1d.end(), 0);
arr1d.fill(0);
```

I could iterate over each array, like so:

```
for (auto& it : arr2d) {
    it.fill(0);
}
```

but it seems it would be much more efficient to fill the array in one pass. Is there a cleaner method for 2D arrays, or am I stuck with C-style pointer logic?

Comment: Why do you assume `std::fill` won't roll a similar loop. If you wish to fill with 0's then `std::memset` could be used.

Comment: @DeiDei One of my goals for my C++ programming is to avoid C-style logic like `memset`. I don't assume either `std::fill` or `std::memset` will or will not roll a loop like my example. I trust that the implementation writers are better programmers than I, and have made optimizations as needed.

Comment: 1. what's the array element type? 2. fill with 0s or with some arbitrary value?

Comment: `std::fill(arr2d.begin(), arr2d.end(), decltype(arr2d)::value_type{0})` or `arr2d.fill(decltype(arr2d)::value_type{0})`. Feel free to spell out the actual type in place of `decltype(arr2d)::value_type`; you gave me no choice but to engage in these hymnastics when you chose to conceal the declaration of `arr2d`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the answer. The type of the array in question is `BYTE`, which is actually a type alias to `std::uint8_t`. Unfortunately, neither of the answers you gave me worked. Using `std::fill` gives me a cryptic STL error, while using `std::array::fill` gives me `error: no matching function for call to 'std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 32ul>, 64ul>::fill(BYTE)'`

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://rextester.com/TULA69835)

Comment: Ah, I see. I specified it as `BYTE{0}` and not `std::array<BYTE, 32>{0}`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In your case, simply assign (or initialize) with `{}`:

```
using arr2d_t = std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 32>, 64>;
arr2d_t arr2d = {}; // all zeroes

arr2d = {}; //ditto
```

Comment: This isn't what I want. I want to empty the array after it has been initialized.

Comment: So assign `{}` to it.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: @robbie0630 You cannot empty an `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to put forward a variant of T.C.'s answer which is useful when working with very large arrays.

When using Visual Studio 2019 (v142 tools) targetting C++ 14, I found that zero-initialisation with `{}` uses a compiler generated temporary variable that consumes stack space, even when the array itself is not located on the stack:

```
std::array<std::array<double, 1024>, 1024> myArray;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    myArray = {}; // <- all zeros but consumes 8,388,608 bytes of stack
    return 0;
}
```

By storing a static copy of a zero-initalised array of matching type, you can then later assign or re-assign the static copy to the array of interest any time you like, which compiles to a single memcpy call:

```
std::array<std::array<double, 1024>, 1024> myArray;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    static const std::array<std::array<double, 1024>, 1024> EmptyArray = {}; // all zeros
    myArray = EmptyArray; // all zeros
    return 0;
}
```